# Java pre increment and post increment and casting with double confusion

Tags: java

Can someone help break this down?

```
double i = 5.5;
i = ++i+i++*(int)i+++i;

System.out.println(i);
```

The answer is 60.5.

Explain step by step please.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: So which step comes first and how is it calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot easier if you was to put it in to the format RadijatoR has stated in the comments.

```
       i = ++i + i++ * (int)i++ + i;
```

This question is testing you on precedence.

increment operators have the highest precedence. So let's deal with them first (We shall do so in a left to right order).

```
i = ++i + i++ * (int)i++ + i;
```

As you can see the first is a pre-increment operator which means i = 5.5+1, prior to the evaluation. The second is a post increment operator, meaning the value of 6.5 will be used, but the next time i is used it will be incremented, hence the third is 7.5 and then is thus post incremented causing the last i to be 8.5.

Now that is out the way we have the following expression:

i = (6.5) + (6.5) * (int) (7.5) + (8.5)

The cast will come second, so 7.5 will be casted to a primitive int of value 7 not 8, java simply chops off the decimal.

We now have:

```
i = (6.5) + (6.5)*(7) + (8.5)
```

Multiplication occurs next so we have 6.5*7 which yields 45.5

```
 i = 6.5 + 45.5 + 8.5
```

This finally yields the result of 60.5, which is what you expected.

So to conclude the order of precedence in this question:

1)Increment operators
2)Casts
3)Multiplication
4)Addition

Answer (score 1):

```
i = ++i + i++ *(int)i + ++i;
```

- ++i = 6.5 +
- (i++ *(int)i) = 45.5 +
- ++i = 8.5  == 60.5

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things involved here to calculate.

1)post-increment  have highest precedence.

2)casting 7.5 to `int` become 7

3) i++ increases in value by 1 and stores it back to `i`

```
double i = 5.5;

i = ++i +(i++) *(int)(i++) +i; // i incremented by 1 and added that to i back (6.5)

i= ++i + 6.5*int(7.5) +8.5; //// i incremented by 1 and added that to i back (7.5)

i= ++i + 6.5*7 +8.5; // casting 7.5 to int is 7 and added the i value 8.5

i= 6.5 +6.5*7 +8.5; 

i= 60.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation should be from left to right

6.5+6.5*7+8.5 =60.5

preincr+postincr*removespoint+post incr+ result of incr